# Variables misbehave in command prompt Windows 10

Tags: windows, variables, cmd

I have a question about variables in Windows cmd.
The task: Run through all directories in the same folder as main script, search for a files with specific name, enter those directories, run those files, return to original folder.

The main script is:

```
SET origin=%~dp0
Echo "%origin%"
cd "%origin%"

for /R .\ %%a IN (*file_to_run_name.cmd) do (
    echo "%%a"
    echo "%%~da%%~pa"
    cd "%%~da%%~pa"
    %%a )

Echo "%origin%"
cd "%origin%"
```

This script does, what I need except of one thing:  it does not change the working directory to the original one. To be more precise, the last fragment:

```
Echo "%origin%"
cd "%origin%"
```

is not even called.

How to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Also, perhaps the last file that matches your `*.file_to_run_name.cmd` filter is never exiting, thus not returning control to the original batch file.

Comment: Variables do not misbehave, but execution control does not return to the main script. Change `%%a` to [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)`"%%~a"`. Replace all [`cd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) by `cd /D`. The string `%%~da%%~pa` can be simplified to [`%%~dpa`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the variables that misbehave. You are trying to run other batch scripts (`.cmd`), and execution control does not return to the main script unless you use [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html). In addition, use [`cd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)`/D` rather than just `/D`, because if the target directory is on another drive, `/D` must be used. And the string `%%~da%%~pa` can be simplified to [`%%~dpa`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Finally, let me recommend to use the quoted [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) syntax to protect special characters.

So here is the fixed code:

```cmd
set "origin=%~dp0"
echo "%origin%"
cd /D "%origin%"

for /R .\ %%a in (*file_to_run_name.cmd) do (
    echo "%%a"
    echo "%%~dpa"
    cd /D "%%~dpa"
    call "%%a"
)

echo "%origin%"
cd /D "%origin%"
```

---

However, this can still be improved: There are the commands [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) (to store the current directory and then to change to a specified one) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) (to restore the previously stored directory), so you do not need to store the original path to a variable.

This is how to apply them:

```cmd
echo "%~dp0"
cd /D "%~dp0"

for /R .\ %%a in (*file_to_run_name.cmd) do (
    echo "%%a"
    echo "%%~dpa"
    pushd "%%~dpa"
    call "%%a"
    popd
)

echo "%CD%"
```